# Bind FormBuilder input value with another input's value

Tags: angular

I have a form with `name` and `milestone` inputs. I want my `milestone`s input value to be `Milestone: + name` and to be updated automatically as my user types a name.

I am trying to use `ngModel` binding in order to achieve this.

```
<!-- My name input -->
<input mdInput [(ngModel)]="phaseName" formControlName="name" placeholder="Nom" required>
```

And in my ts components constructor:

```
public phaseForm: FormGroup;
phaseName: string;

this.phaseForm = fb.group({
        'name': ['', Validators.required],
        'milestone': ['Milestone: ' + this.phaseName, Validators.required]
    });
```

But as the default value of milestone is set in the constructor, it does not update as my user types a name, what should I add or do in order to achieve my binding?

Comment: don't initialize in the constructor. use `ngOninit` to initialize the value and use can get the values by `this.phaseForm.value`. no need of `ngModel`

Comment: But I want the value to be changed as the user types

Comment: it will change. eventually. check by adding {{pahseForm.value.name}} in your html. In your .ts access it by `this.pahseForm.value.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you can set like that. after init form builder in ngOnInit() method.
>   if you can use input box inside formgroup. it's already two way
>   binding so no need bind a value. if you want to get form value.

```
for eg : const phaseFormValue = this.pahseForm.value;
 console.log(phaseFormValue.name);

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.phaseForm.setValue({milestone:'Milestone: ' + this.phaseName});
}
```

> if you can use input box outside. then try this code.

```
<input mdInput [(ngModel)]="phaseName" (keypress)="handleKeyboardEvent($event)" placeholder="Name">
```

// component

```
@HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
            this.phaseForm.setValue({milestone:'Milestone: ' + this.phaseName});
    };
```

Comment: How would that help bind the value of the milestone to the name in real time?

Comment: you need to remove ngModel and  (data driven method) formControlName is two way binding.

Comment: @Chris you can used phaseName input box inside form or outside?

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
<input mdInput formControlName="name" placeholder="Nom" required>

* no need of ngModel
```

Component

To get value

`this.phaseForm.value`

and to detect changes you can do

`this.phaseForm.valueChanges
      .subscribe(data => this.onValueChanged(data));`

for the single property, you could do like

```
nameChangeLog: string[] = [];
logNameChange() {
  const nameControl = this.heroForm.get('name');
  nameControl.valueChanges.forEach(
    (value: string) => this.nameChangeLog.push(value)
  );
}
```

check the [cookbook here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html)

you can initialize value as suggested by Shailesh Ladumor or
at the place where you initialize the form.

Comment: But this would catch changes on all fields of my form, how can I target a single field (such as name)?